Highcharts Spline Chart: Tooltips Displaying Incorrect Data on Hover
I'm encountering an issue with a spline chart created using Highcharts in my React application. When hovering over a data point on the chart, the tooltip sometimes displays data for a different point, rather than the expected point. The configuration options for the chart were pulled from one of the examples provided by Highcharts.
Here's the configuration I'm using for the chart:


{
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      inverted: true
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Atmosphere Temperature by Altitude',
      align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'According to the Standard Atmosphere Model',
      align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
      reversed: false,
      title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Altitude'
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value} km'
      },
      accessibility: {
        rangeDescription: 'Range: 0 to 80 km.'
      },
      maxPadding: 0.05,
      showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value}°'
      },
      accessibility: {
        rangeDescription: 'Range: -90°C to 20°C.'
      },
      lineWidth: 2
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
      pointFormat: '{point.x} km: {point.y}°C',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      spline: {
        marker: {
          enable: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Temperature',
      stickyTracking: false,
      findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
      data: [[0, 15], [10, -50], [20, -56.5], [30, -46.5], [40, -22.1],
      [50, -2.5], [60, -27.7], [70, -55.7], [80, -76.5]]

    }]
  }



[![enter image description here][1]][1]
In below screenshot i hovered on first point, but the tooltip showed for 4th.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/txh8q.png

Hi, I just recreated this example to the online demo and I do not see any issues with tooltip: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-forked-pdlc9p?file=%2Fdemo.jsx . Could you please reproduce your issue in the online demo?

hi @magdalena, i copied it from their highcharts sample that is why it is working fine on your example... but problem is that this same json gives issue in my application and not able to figure out the solution

Please try to reproduce the issue in the online demo so that I can assist you further. Unfortunately, I cannot help without the issue being recreated.
